# "Kill" an open JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I have a class that extends JFrame that represents a dialog window for my program. This dialog accepts user input through a text field. Depending on the input, the window may also update with a different message (stored as a JLabel), if need be.

I noticed that when I click on a button in the dialog (which in my code, disposes the dialog), if I activate the dialog again (by selecting the control that initiates the dialog in the first place), the text I previously entered, and also the state of the JLabel remains. I am looking for a way to "kill" the running instance of the dialog when it disappears, so when it does appear again, it is "new," with a blank text field and the default JLabel. Is this possible?

Comment: for better help sooner post an  [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about a.m. issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are maintaining a reference to the frame.

Instead, you may want to use `JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE)` to dispose of the frames underlying native resources and re-create it again when you need it.

**Updated**

When you are done with the frame in you main code, simply settle variable to `null`. In your code that displays the frame, you would need to do a `null` check and recreate the frame as required

Comment: How do I dereference the frame? You are right, right now I am just hiding the frame. dispose() doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Comment: Basically use frame = null

Answer (score 0):

did you try to set `JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`??

Comment: This is a (nice) comment, but `JFrame#setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE)` might be better, but it sounds like they aren't dereferencing the original frame, so neither of these are likely to work...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I really think that OP is setting the visibility of the JFrame to `false` .. but then again, he really needs to post a SSCCE

Answer (score 0):

`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`

This will close only one window if you have multiple windows with your program open.  When only one window is left, and it is closed, the program stops.